# How to use Class.forName() method in Java with primitive type (int , float, double, char ...)

Tags: java, introspection

I have declared a method that return `Class`, but i don't know if it is the right way or not .
When i pass `int`, `float`, `double` or `String` as parameter, i want to return `int.class`, `float.class` or `double.class`.

> How can i do that?

```
Class<?> analyseType(String nameType) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> classe = Class.forName(nameType);
        return classe; 
    }
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.ClassLoader)): "_If `name` denotes a primitive type or void, an attempt will be made to locate a user-defined class in the unnamed package whose name is `name`. Therefore, this method cannot be used to obtain any of the Class objects representing primitive types or void_".

Comment: I still have a problem with String , when I have an input as "String", how should i do ?

Comment: The `Class.forName` method expects a fully qualified name and, despite its special treatment, `String` is _not_ a primitive type. You should pass "java.lang.String".

Comment: Starting with Java 22, you will be able to write, e.g. `Class.forPrimitiveName("int")`